# Typescript Extend class from other ts file

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, typescript

I have three classes in three different .ts files. ClassA, ClassB and ClassC.

In the first file there is:

```
//file a.ts
class ClassA {

}
```

The second file is:

```
//file b.ts
export class ClassB extends ClassA {

}
```

The third file is:

```
//file c.ts
export class ClassC extends ClassA {

}
```

When i build the files with typescript via grunt there aren't errors.
But if i try to import ClassB or ClassC and try to instance them there is this error:

> node .\index.js
>
> ..etc..etc.\b.js:13 })(ClassA);    ^
>
> ReferenceError: ClassA is not defined
>       at Object. (........\b.js:13:4)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object. (.....\index.js:3:19)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)

The code in index.js is:

```
var ClassB = require('./src/b')

var CB = new ClassB();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to export class A to use it in another .ts file.

```
export class classA{

}
```

and should import it wherever you want to use it.

```
import {classA} from 'pathName'
```